# C++ - How to create a property that can be used with _ inside the class?

Tags: c++, templates, properties

I currently have this:

```
template <typename T>
class property<T, kPropertyReadOnly> {

    T value;

public:
    property() {}
    property(T initValue) : value(initValue){}

    T & operator = (const T &i) {
        return value = i;
    }

    operator T const & () const {
        return value;
    }
};
```

Which kind of brings properties to C++. Let's say we have a class:

```
class foo {
   property<int> myProperty;
}
```

Then I'd like to be able to use the property from the outside world like this:

```
Foo foo();
foo.myProperty = 2;
```

But inside the class Foo, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
void Foo::myFooFunction() {
    _myProperty = 2;     
}
```

This way it's very clear what is an instance variable/property but when used from the outside you don't have to do this ugly thing:

```
foo._myProperty = 2;
```

I know templates can do lots of magic, but can they do this?

Comment: To reduce the possibility of collision with the compiler's symbols, I recommend using the '_' as a *suffix* (at the end), rather than as a *prefix* (at the beginning).

Comment: Can you explain further why? I would like to use it at the beginning because then autocompletion helps a lot, when typing underscore you see all member variables.

Comment: Because according to the language standard, preceding underscores are reserved for compiler symbols.  A language lawyer or somebody with a copy of the standard can reference the exact location.  Or you can search the internet for "c++ leading underscores compiler".

Comment: @Thomas It is not exactly that. Two consequitive underscores anywhere are reserved and underscore followed by _capital_ letter at the beginning is reserved too. Second one is not actually reserved everywhere, but I found that it is easier to treat as if it was.

Comment: Just a note of caution: having both a constructor that takes `T` and a conversion to `T` will at some point lead to ambiguities. You'll end up marking one of them `explicit`.

Comment: What exactly is a conversion to T?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question well, what you can do is interface your private variable with a public reference to it:

```
class Foo {
  property<int> _myProperty;
public:
  property<int> &myProperty = _myProperty;

  void myFooFunction() {
    _myProperty = 2;     
  }
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e86830648292bf1)

Comment: Hey, again ;) Yes, this works, thank you. But is there a more elegant solution, that does not need two separate lines?

Comment: @keyboard I don't think so. You need at least two lines one for the variable and one for the alias ;)

Comment: Okay, thank you. Maybe I'll go for a define then that does it for me ;)

Comment: I've got a follow up question, would be really cool if you could have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403518/c-declaration-and-instantiation-code-compiles-for-ios-and-osx-but-not-for-an